# Facing Checksum issues on installing bower

Tags: bower, npm-install

```
D:\businessapp>npm install -g bower
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! node v5.6.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.6.0

npm ERR! shasum check failed for C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-4160-e9917
a21\registry.npmjs.org\bower\-\bower-1.7.7.tgz
npm ERR! Expected: 2fd7ff3ebdcba5a8ffcd84c397c8fdfe9f825f92
npm ERR! Actual:   399d3692e031c8527fa361cd93915f30cec3b0c2
npm ERR! From:     https://registry.npmjs.org/bower/-/bower-1.7.7.tgz
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

Is it related to downloading something?

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall node.js and npm modules?

Comment: I tried two times with the same command and both the times failed, only difference is the Actual is different. Do I need to reinstall nodejs again?

Comment: Delete temporary files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a checksum poblem. Found solution from [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7991).

Solution is :

```
npm cache clean bower
```

Then run the install command again.